# Does the single word 'equimolar' have single-word equivalents for less than or greater than?

Tags: terminology

Does the single word 'equimolar' have single-word equivalents for less than or greater than?  If there isn't an officially accepted word for these, could a neologism be improvised using linguistic conventions?

Comment: I would imagine ‘hypomolar’ and ‘hypermolar’, though these both have a problem that equimolar does not: the ordering of the arguments is now critical. For the direct antonym, people appear to use ‘non-equimolar’.

Comment: multimolar,  (since *equi-* is a Latin prefix.)

Comment: The submolar quantities of N-terminals in proteins is the title of another paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all prefixes, Latin and Greek, imply a comparison with Molar solutions as 1.00.

hence: 'values of inframolar solutions,' '...question as to whether an inframolar dose might be effective.'

similarly: 'Conformational study of spectrin in presence of submolar concentrations of denaturants.' and the antonym: 'Supramolar recognition and organization of (bio) molecules around carbon nanotubes.'

hypermolar appears to mean the same thing in this particular paper: Hypermolar Buffers (and other treatments) to Unmask IgG Complexes
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9692879
**Also**  eurekamag.com/research/006/133/006133206.php 
Biguet J., 1982: Plasmodium falciparum in vitro development and volume variations in hypo molar and hyper molar media.

Hyperosmolar is used exclusively of  Hyperglycemic blood building osmotic pressure,

> The **only** paper which may have **hyper molar & hypo molar in the
>   sense  you intend** is a patent from 1982.
>   https://www.google.com/patents/US4172071 23 Oct 1979 - '...
>   equilibrated with an aqueous buffer whose concentration in salts is
>   isomolar or hypomolar as compared with that of blood, and separating
>   the...'

...and even here as you see the terms are qualified. In all other cases **'concentration'** appears to be the preferred term.

(Paramolar and hypomolar lead the unwary into dentistry.)